# What meta/link html tags important for seo?

Tags: html, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New META TAGS with positive effects for seo ranking in 2011 and beyond](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6185/new-meta-tags-with-positive-effects-for-seo-ranking-in-2011-and-beyond)

What are meta tags important for seo? Especially for blogs. I often find something new, maybe you will correct me and add something else?

```
meta name = description - description of page
http-equiv = Content-Language content = "ru" - language of page
http-equiv = "Content-Type" content = "text / html; charset = utf-8"
rel = "alternate" type = "application / rss + xml" - Link for RSS-chanel
```

Another thing I remembered but had forgotten indication nofollow / follow, index / noindex on the page. Somebody remind me?
I also saw a Wordpress rel = next / previous page is important for SEO?
Something else that I do not have?

Comment: Something of a reference : http://blog.kissmetrics.com/seo-guide/

Comment: And sort of a duplicate of [this question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3013/uses-of-link-tag), too.

Answer (score 2):

SEO wise they're getting less important than they used to be. Google seems to take **page content** more into account now but they're still useful to have in place. Other search engines still place more importance in them than Google do.

There's a very good reference here - http://www.metatags.org/all_metatags

Highlights are:

```
<title>relevant and attractive phrase </title>
```

The title is the first (usually click-able) phrase you see as a search result.

```
<meta name="description" content="text">
```

A description of your website in 3 of 4 sentences.

```
<meta name="keywords" content="words">
```

The keywords are the most important words you use on 1 specific page.

```
<meta name="robots" content="selection">
```

How far do you allow robots to spider through your website.

Answer (score 1):

Well, recommended tags are:

Meta Content Language

Meta Content Type

Meta Description

Meta Language

And optional tags:

Meta Abstract

Meta Author

Meta Copyright

Meta Designer

Meta Google

Meta Keywords

Meta MSN (No ODP)

Meta Title

Yo can get more information from:

http://www.webmarketingnow.com/tips/meta-tags-uncovered.html

http://www.seoconsultants.com/meta-tags/

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

These are the ones I use to put in my files. Normally are considered as important ones.

```
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="keywords">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="description">
<META NAME="Title" CONTENT="title">
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="author">
<META NAME="Subject" CONTENT="theme">
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="generator">
<META NAME="Language" CONTENT="language">
<META NAME="Robots" CONTENT="index, follow">
```

Obviously, you have to put the right "content", and not what I filled inside.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In times like this I really think you should include Open Graph Meta as well. That's then ones that Facebook uses.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/